# Trying to Integrate Mail Into my app, getting 2 warnings

Tags: objective-c, email, integration, cocos2d-iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to integrate sending mail into my app, but I end up with 2 warnings. I am using Obj-C, the Cocos2d Framework. This is my code.

```
    -(void) mailTapped: (id) sender {
 MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
  [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
  [composer setSubject:@"Check Out This Awesome App!"];
  [composer setMessageBody:@"I found this great game on the App Store! It's called Mole Attack. It's a side scroller with an epic story. You can check out some screenshots of the gameplay and download it here. Download link - " isHTML:NO]; //Include link and pics
  [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];  // <--- warning - GameOver (name of class) may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'
 }
} 

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // <--- warning - GameOver may not respond to '-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES'
 if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"The email was not sent. You must be in wifi or 3G range. Try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `GameOver` class is inheriting from `UIViewController`? That's the class that defines the two methods that you're getting warnings about.

Comment: Ahh, that's the problem! It's just that I'm not sure how I can make it UIVewController, because I need to keep it at CCLayer because I'm using Cocos2d.